# EC2 instance launched from AMI not reachable(ssh) after start/stop or reboot

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rhel, amazon-ami

When we launch an instance from an AMI. At first the instance is accessible(ssh). Once we stop/start the instance or reboot it the machine becomes inaccessible via ssh,we can ping it though. We see below error in System log.

```
AMI ID used - ami-72dc9220
Instance - i-0896a15f - 

Linux rhel6.4 M1.large instance.
../

******************* BLKFRONT for device/vbd/2049 **********
backend at /local/domain/0/backend/vbd/236/2049
Failed to read /local/domain/0/backend/vbd/236/2049/feature-barrier.
Failed to read /local/domain/0/backend/vbd/236/2049/feature-flush-cache.
14680064 sectors of 512 bytes
**************************
Thread "kbdfront": pointer: 0x21e0130010, stack: 0x3720000
FBFRONT for device/vfb/0 **********
KBDFRONT for device/vkbd/0 **********
Failed to read device/vfb/0/backend-id.
Failed to read device/vkbd/0/backend-id.
Error ENOENT when reading the backend path device/vkbd/0/backend
Thread "kbdfront" exited.
Error ENOENT when reading the backend path device/vfb/0/backend

./
```

Comment: Did you check the new public IP/DNS of the instance?

Comment: yes I did. Its the random assigned Ip "ec2-54-251-X-Y.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com" after reboot. We are not using Elastic IP for this. I can ping the public IP and system log has the above error.

Comment: I dont understand why this got a downvote. I have faced this weird but very serious issue too. And as the user commented, it seems to be a bug.

Answer (score 8):

Was able to fix this. This is due to [a bug from REDHAT for 6.4 rhel instances](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=956531). 
After launching the machine from an AMI, connect to the machine and switch to root user and make below changes to  `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` file ...

Remove the following three lines and save the file:

```
cat <<EOL >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config 
UseDNS no 
PermitRootLogin without-password
../
```

One should also remove garbage entries from `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file.

The machine once rebooted after these changes works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Also comment following lines in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
permitrootlogin without-password
permitrootlogin without-passwordUseDNS no
```